# ERD relationships don't make sense in access database

Tags: ms-access, database-design, erd

I am creating a database as a final project for a class. This is my first time ever creating a database and I am having some trouble.

Now the business I am doing this for does not really have any business rules, at least that I could get from any of the three managers working there. So what I came up with based off of what they do and what I know from working there is:

- One to many employees have rows in the cash accountability table, each employee only has one row in the table.

  - One to many employees clock in and out, but each employee only has one record in the system.
  - All employees have wages, but each employee only has one wage
  - There are many department leads, but only one lead in each department
  - each department lead is only lead in one department

That is how I based this ERD, but when actually creating a database with these relationships, it does not work. I want to figure out how to get this ERD corrected so the relationships in the database are correct. When I created the database, instead of the employee table having three primary keys, the wage, cash accountability, and time clock table all had the employee id as the foreign key and the database worked fine for the purpose.

[image: ERD]
Here is a link to the ERD

Comment: @Brad No it doesn't. This only contains a database design, not any code. This is off-topic for Code Review. To avoid questions getting closed on multiple sites, please either flag for migration with a custom flag (so that moderators can reject it or not) or vote to close *because it is off-topic for SO, not because you think it belongs somewhere else*

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg sorry, I just did a quick search of code review and found plenty of questions looking for review of a database design which included an ERD. IT didn't seem material that the ERD was expressed as a picture and not CREATE statements since the concept is the same.

Comment: @Brad at [codereview.se], we *review **code***, thereby any question without any code can't possibly be on-topic. It's a non-starter.

Comment: @nhgrif [fair enough](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74/should-design-questions-be-on-topic-here). I guess the place for this is Programmers then?

Comment: @Brad Are you absolutely certain this question is off-topic for [so]? It has an already accepted answer. Is it necessary to migrate?

Comment: @Brad come on **seriously??** You got put down for suggesting migration to CR uninformedly, and now you're trying to do the same thing for Programmers? Read the **help center** of sites, before recommending a migration. And if you're even slightly unsure: **Better don't**

Comment: @nhgrif meh, I voted then I wrote up an answer after the fact...I'll just give this up now

Comment: Thanks everyone for the wisdom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments/questions:

1. If you are going to put Wages in a separate table then you may as well make it `1:many`. i.e. put `EmpID` in `Wages` and remove `WageID` from `Employee`. This lets you keep track of multiple wages per employee which is the reality because wages usually changes. You could have a wage begindate/enddate (i.e. Employee1234 was paid 10k $ in 2011 and 15k $ in 2012). As it is right now with a 1:1 relationship you may as well have it be in one table.
2. I'm not following your `TimeClock` structure. As you have it written an employee can only clock in/clock out once ever. Sure they will show  up to work on Tuesday.
3. Same logic in the `CashAccountability`. Every employee can only be responsibly for one cash-out.  I think you are looking for a many-to-many relationship here, you should research how to implement that sort of data structure. Basically it allows for a `CashAccountability` to be linked to multiple employees and for an employees to be linked to multiple `CashAccountability`s.
4. You have a way of designating a department lead but there is not way to show what employees are under the lead. i.e. no link to a department for subordinates.

Edit:

I see your question now about why the Employee table does not have a 3 column primary key. A primary key is whatever you want it to be but it would not be logical to involve things that are not about the employee as a person in the employee table and especially not as a primary key for identifying that person. WageID, TimeID and CashID have nothing to do with the employee per se thus they should not be in the employee table and certainly not be in the primary key.

Comment: The way the job is, the wages don't change only when there is a minimum wage increase which is why it was that way. The EmpID was in the wages table in the access database, I was just having trouble mirroring that in the ERD. Also, even though there is a dept lead title, there are no subordinates actually under the lead. That's why there is no linking for that. @Brad

Comment: `the wages don't change [except] when there is a minimum wage increase`. So they can change? However, if you want to only have one wage per employee then put it in the employee table. If that's the case then there is no point putting it in a separate table. It is an unnecessary join.

Comment: I have changed the relationship. Thank you, I was reading the relationships such as the one with the time clock table as one employee clocks in once a day so they only have one row in the table but it makes much more sense as an employee clocks in many times over the course of employment. The wage and time clock table now have the EmpId as foreign keys and zero to many relationships. @Brad